# Why does my simple counting program take longer to run with multiple threads? (in C)

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, runtime

Here's my code:

```
#define COUNT_TO 100000000
#define MAX_CORES 4

static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
long long i = 0;

void* start_counting(void *arg){
    for(;;){

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        if(i >= COUNT_TO){
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            return NULL;
        }
        i++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        //printf("i = %lld\n", i);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i = 0;

    pthread_t * thread_group = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * MAX_CORES);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_CORES; i++){
        pthread_create(&thread_group[i], NULL, start_counting, NULL);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_CORES; i++){
        pthread_join(thread_group[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because that mutex management isn't free, and a non-threaded single-loop version of this would probably optimize down to literally nothing.

Comment: All the threads are serialised by the lock/unlock.  That is, there is no effective parallelisation but there is the cost of running the synchronisation and swapping of threads. Just throwing threads at a problem is not enough. You need to actually break up the work such that it can be run in parallel without major interlocking and the work needs to be significant enough to make it worth the overheads of thread switching.

Comment: I removed the mutex locks with my tests and it improved the runtime with multiple threads but it's still much slower than a single thread. I'm brand new to multithreading but I feel like that shouldn't happen?

Comment: The short answer is that the problem being solved is not worth parallelising and the cost of the thread overhead is too high compared to the work being done. And removing the lock is not the right answer in any case as that means the code is not thread safe - they all try to read and increment the same variable in a race condition which means the code becomes functionally incorrect.

Comment: Imagine I had a glass of wine. Would it be quicker for a single person to drink it all in one go or do you think it would be faster to pass the wine around in a circle with each person taking one sip? But if I had 5 glasses of wine and every one could have a different glass then having 5 people would be faster than having 1. That is, you need to look at the problem being solved to see if it makes sense to parallelise in the first place.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, at least I know it's not anything that i'm doing wrong per say. In your opinion is there a decent way of knowing what sort of cases would improve the runtime with multiple threads? maybe two different functions running in parallel, in this case each function would just count to half of what I'm counting to then adding them up after a thread join?

Comment: There's no hard or fast rule. But in general the work should be such that the threads can do most of the work without interacting with any other threads. That is, the part that needs to be locked (ie, the critical section) should be fairly short compared to the work being done that doesn't need to be locked.

Comment: ok that makes sense, thanks for the info, I'll keep this in mind!

Comment: Don’t know whether C permits this, but in other languages, with a smart compiler, your program gets compiled to a program that simply assigns `COUNT_TO` to `i` in the first thread with all other thread doing almost nothing. Then, the more threads you create, the more overhead you have, without altering the result at all.

Comment: Multithreading is not a silver bullet that automatically grants more performance

Answer (score 1):

This is what your threads do:

1. Read the value of `i`.
2. Increment the value we read.
3. Write back the incremented value of `i`.
4. Go to step 1.

Cleary, another thread cannot read the value of `i` after a different thread has accomplished step 1 but before it has completed step 3. So there can be no overlap between two threads doing steps 1, 2, or 3.

So all your threads are fighting over access to the same resource -- `i` (or the mutex that protects it). No thread can make useful forward progress without exclusive access to one or both of those. Given that, there is no benefit to using multiple threads since only one of them can accomplish useful work at a time.